# Knapsack class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, knapsack-problem

This is a simple implementation of a [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) written in Ruby.  I've included all the relevant code here, but my question is concerning the contents setter `.contents=`

```
## item.rb
class Item
  attr_accessor :weight
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(weight:, data: nil)
    @weight = weight
    @data   = data
  end

end




 ## knapsack.rb
class KnapsackCapacityExceededError < StandardError; end
class KnapsackWeightExceededError < StandardError; end
class KnapsackContentError < StandardError; end

require_relative('./item')

class Knapsack
  attr_reader :capacity
  attr_reader :weight
  attr_reader :contents

  def initialize(capacity:, weight:)
    @capacity = capacity
    @weight   = weight
    @contents = Array.new(@capacity) { nil }
  end

  def contents=(new_contents)
    raise KnapsackCapacityExceededError if self.exceeds_capacity? new_contents
    raise KnapsackWeightExceededError   if self.exceeds_weight? new_contents
    raise KnapsackContentError          unless new_contents.all? { |e| e.is_a? Item }

    @contents = new_contents
  end

  def fit?(contents)
    return false if self.exceeds_weight?(contents) || self.exceeds_capacity?(contents)
    true
  end
  alias_method :fits?, :fit?

  def fits_weight?(contents)
    new_weight = contents.map { |item| item.weight }.sum
    return true if new_weight <= self.weight
    false
  end

  def exceeds_weight?(contents)
    return true if !fits_weight? contents
    false
  end

  def fits_capacity?(contents)
    return true if contents.length <= self.capacity
    false
  end

  def exceeds_capacity?(contents)
    return true if !fits_capacity? contents
    false
  end

end

# k = Knapsack.new(capacity: 10, weight: 50)
```

In this method there are three conditions where an exception is raised, is this a code smell?

Any other feedback also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are multiple things. First of all I'll share the code refactoring related suggestions and then we can look at the performance improvements of code.

### Refactoring

1. You don't really need to pass a block to `Array.new` to initialize the array with `nil` values.

   ```
   def initialize(capacity:, weight:)
     @capacity = capacity
     @weight   = weight
     @contents = Array.new(@capacity) { nil }
   end
   ```

   can be refactored to:

   ```
   def initialize(capacity:, weight:)
     @capacity = capacity
     @weight   = weight
     @contents = Array.new(@capacity)
   end
   ```
2. ```
   def contents=(new_contents)
     raise KnapsackCapacityExceededError if self.exceeds_capacity? new_contents
     raise KnapsackWeightExceededError   if self.exceeds_weight? new_contents
     raise KnapsackContentError          unless new_contents.all? { |e| e.is_a? Item }

     @contents = new_contents
   end
   ```

   can be refactored to:

   ```
   def contents=(new_contents)
     raise KnapsackCapacityExceededError if exceeds_capacity? new_contents
     raise KnapsackWeightExceededError   if exceeds_weight? new_contents
     raise KnapsackContentError          if has_non_items? new_contents

     @contents = new_contents
   end

   def has_non_items?(contents)
     contents.any? { |content| !content.is_a?(Item) }
   end
   ```

   -> Notice that usage of `self` keyword has been removed.

   -> Moved the logic of checking any non-items in contents to a separate method. That makes the if conditions more readable and it replaces the `unless` with `if` to make it consistent with rest of the conditions.
3. Method `fit?` can be refactored to:

   ```
   def fit?(contents)
     fits_weight?(contents) && fits_capacity?(contents)
   end
   ```
4. Method `fits_weight?` can be refactored as well.

   ```
   def fits_weight?(contents)
     contents.map(&:weight).sum <= weight
   end
   ```

### Performance Tuning

You don't need to initialize the `@contents` array with `nil` elements. You can just write `@contents = []` to save some extra used memory.

Comment: All good points.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Graipher thanks for the changes. They look good to me

Answer (score 2):

First of all `return true if ... else false` is not necessary. Just return the original condition. For example:

```
  def fit?(contents)
    fits_weight?(contents) && fits_capacity?(contents)
  end
```

---

Next, `self.` is not necessary in most cases, including every case it is used in this program. `self.weight` should be replaced with `@weight`.

---

`knapsack.rb` should look more like:

```
class KnapsackCapacityExceededError < StandardError; end
class KnapsackWeightExceededError < StandardError; end
class KnapsackContentError < StandardError; end

require_relative('./item')

class Knapsack
  attr_reader :capacity
  attr_reader :weight
  attr_reader :contents

  def initialize(capacity:, weight:)
    @capacity = capacity
    @weight   = weight
    @contents = Array.new(@capacity) { nil }
  end

  def contents=(new_contents)
    raise KnapsackCapacityExceededError if exceeds_capacity? new_contents
    raise KnapsackWeightExceededError   if exceeds_weight? new_contents
    raise KnapsackContentError          if new_contents.any? { |e| !e.is_a? Item }

    @contents = new_contents
  end

  def fit?(contents)
    fits_weight?(contents) && fits_capacity?(contents)
  end
  alias_method :fits?, :fit?

  def fits_weight?(contents)
    new_weight = contents.map { |item| item.weight }.sum
    new_weight <= @weight
  end

  def exceeds_weight?(contents)
    !fits_weight? contents
  end

  def fits_capacity?(contents)
    contents.length <= @capacity
  end

  def exceeds_capacity?(contents)
    !fits_capacity? contents
  end

end
```

---

I do not think that three `raise` conditions are a problem. That code is clear and simple. The three exception classes may be a bit much.

Comment: Bit off topic, but maybe replace `contents.map { |item| item.weight }.sum` with `contents.sum(&:weight)`. I'd be tempted to replace `new_contents.any? { |e| !e.is_a? Item }` with `new_contents.all? { |e| e.is_a? Item }` also.